# Upload static library (protobuf .a) as cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, static-libraries, lipo

I can't seem to understand how to upload a static library and public headers as a cocoapod. All I want to achieve is that by installing this pod it would pull .a file and few headers and link it with my .xcodeproj.

1. I've built a protobuf for all architectures and made one universal library with lipo.
2. I put the headers and .a file into folder, zipped it and uploaded to a storage and made it accessible with a public link.

```css
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
      s.name         = "Protobuf"
      s.version      = "0.2.4"
      s.license      = { :type => "MIT" }
      s.homepage     = "https://github.com/Rostyk/Protobuf"
      s.author       = { "Ross" => "ros.aphex@gmail.com" }
      s.summary      = "Protobuf binary"
      s.source       = { :http => 
        'https://www.dropbox.com/s/gon6x99xjp6hh9g/protobuf.zip?dl=1', :tag => "v0.2.4" }
    end
```

When I do `pod lib lint Protobuf.podspec --verbose` it outputs:

```
Protobuf did not pass validation, due to 2 errors and 1 warning.
[!] The validator for Swift projects uses Swift 3.0 by default, if you
are using a different version of swift you can use a 
`.swift-version` file to set the version for your Pod. For example to use Swift 2.3,
run: `echo "2.3" > .swift-version`.
You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.
```

I looked through [this article about binary cocoapods](http://markspanbroek.github.io/2016/04/14/binary-cocoapods.html)

Unfortunately I don't have any experience with pods. Maybe someone will point me to the right direction?

Comment: You're missing the vendored_frameworks field

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this out. That's the working podspec in case someone needs

```css
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'DMProtobuf'
  s.version  = '1.0.1'
  s.license  = 'BSD'
  s.summary  = 'Protobuf for iOS'
  s.description  = 'Static library with protobuf utilities'
  s.homepage = 'https://homepage.sample.com'
  s.author       = 'Google'
  s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/YourAccount/Repo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.preserve_paths = '*.a'
  s.libraries = 'protobuf'
  s.xcconfig     =  { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) "$(PODS_ROOT)/DMProtobuf"' }
  s.platform = :ios
end
```

Also don't forget to tag your branch with '1.0.1'